# insert into mysql if not exist and dont update if exsist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have function code like this:

```
$data_temp = $this->import_m->getPresensi()->result_array();


    $tbl = "tb_kehadiran";    
    $tbl_temp = "tb_kehadiran_temp";
    $db_mysql = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
    $db_mysql->trans_start();

    foreach($data_temp as $k => $v){

        $dataTemp = array(

            'colUserID' => $v['userID'],
            'colDate' => $v['tanggal'],
            'colJamMasuk' => $v['jam_masuk'],
            'colJamKeluar' => $v['jam_keluar'],
            'colTerlambat' => $v['late'],
            'colLemburPagi' => $v['lembur_pagi'],
            'colLemburSore' => $v['lembur_sore']

            );  

        $sql = "INSER INTO $tbl (
                    'colUserID',
                    'colDate',
                    'colJamMasuk',
                    'colJamKeluar',
                    'colTerlambat',
                    'colLemburPagi',
                    'colLemburSore'
                 ) VALUES (
                    $v[userID],
                    $v[tanggal],
                    $v[jam_masuk],
                    $v[jam_keluar],
                    $v[late],
                    $v[lembur_pagi],
                    $v[lembur_sore]
                ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    'colJamMasuk' = $v[jam_masuk],
                    'colJamKeluar' = $v[jam_keluar],
                    'colTerlambat' = $v[late],
                    'colLemburPagi' = $v[lembur_pagi],
                    'colLemburSore' = $v[lembur_sore]
                ";
        $db_mysql->query($sql);

    }

    $db_mysql->trans_complete();
    $db_mysql->close();
```

the result error:
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

`'INSER INTO tb_kehadiran ( 'colUserID', ' at line 1`

```
INSER INTO tb_kehadiran ( 'colUserID', 'colDate', 'colJamMasuk', 'colJamKeluar', 'colTerlambat', 'colLemburPagi', 'colLemburSore' ) VALUES ( 1, 2015-01-05, 07:01:00, 16:30:00, 00:00:00.000000, 00:28:16.000000, 00:00:43.000000 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'colJamMasuk' = 07:01:00, 'colJamKeluar' = 16:30:00, 'colTerlambat' = 00:00:00.000000, 'colLemburPagi' = 00:28:16.000000, 'colLemburSore' = 00:00:43.000000

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\presensi\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

I want my source code insert the data if the data no exist an not update if data is exist.
 please help me.

Comment: You're missing a t in inserT

Comment: It's INSERT not INSER :)

Answer (score 0):

code must be like that

insert into table_name set id= "some_id",
                                           name = 'some_name'
                                           on duplicate key update
                                           name = 'some_name'

also the id field must be defined as primary key

Comment: OP's syntax is as valid as your.

Comment: @lelio faieta plz echo your sql query

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: sorry not for you its for @willy andika

Comment: OP's issue is already solved. It was a typo in the inser vs insert statement in the query